# Gradle 6.5 issue with plugin “com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3

Tags: gradle

I am really annoyed with com.gradle.enterprise plugin as the id and groupid different

I finally tried to redirect using

```
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://artifactory.XXX/artifactory/public/" }
        }
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                if (requested.id.id == "com.gradle.enterprise") {
                    useModule("com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3")
                }
            }
        }
    }

plugins {
    id "com.gradle.enterprise" version "3.3.3"
}
```

Now all I am getting the error is
**Plugin not found in org.gradle instead of searching in com.gradle**

Exception is:

```
 org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: ‘com.gradle.enterprise’, version: ‘3.3.3’, artifact: ‘com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3’] was not found in any
    
    of the following sources:
    
    Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in ‘org.gradle’ namespace)
    
    Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact ‘com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3’)
```

Comment: I have the same issue in code. may you say how you solved this issue?

Comment: I need enterprise only for scan cmd so I started using -debug or -stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

To enable build scans with `--scan`, you can add the repository to your `settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
    }
}
```